products.map is not a function in console.log() data got
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Page() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState(null); 

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products");
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data)
                setProducts(data); 
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    if (products === null) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>; 
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Product List</h1>
            <ul>
                {products.map((product, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>{product.name}</li> 
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

Error:

unhandled Runtime error
products.map is not a function

Why is products.map not a function? Please tell me why. console.log(data) I got API data but not display on browser

The API response with products attribute setProducts(data.products);

you are setting products as null on the useState, put an empty array instead.
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

" I got API data" is that response data an array? Because if it isn't you're going to see that error...

data needs to be an array. If it's anything but an array you can't map over it.

As the others have mentioned the api does not return the product list directly, but as a nested key.
Since you are trying to use map on a datatype that does not implement it, it throws an error. map is only defined for the array datatype (Array#map).
The response looks like this:
type ApiResponse = {
  limit: number;
  products: Array<{
    brand: string;
    category: string;
    description: string;
    discountPercentage: number;
    id: number;
    images: Array<string>;
    price: number;
    rating: number;
    stock: number;
    thumbnail: string;
    title: string;
  }>;
  skip: number;
  total: number;
};

Which means that you need to use setProducts(data.products) instead of setProducts(data).
You also need to change from
<li key="{index}">{product.name}</li>

to
<li key="{index}">{product.title}</li>

since product doesn't have any key named name.
